# Is there a way to reference Airflow task group by group_id similar to referencing tasks dag_instance.get_task('task_name')?

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to find a way to reference task group by it's id.
something like:

```
dag.get_group('group_id')
```

I know how to get task instance with `get_task('task_id')` method, but strangely there is no way I could find to do the same with TaskGroup objects.

Any workarounds that you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
tg = dag.task_group.get_child_by_label(group_id)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).